# Acceleration Of A Ball (Changing Directions)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

Acceleration is regarded as a change in velocity, so what will be the acceleration of this ball in the figure, as its magnitude is constant, but the direction is changing.

[image]

Comment: $a=dv/dt$ , i.e  change in velocity / time duration

Answer (score 0):

If the curved bit of your trajectory is an arc of a circle radius $R$ then the magnitude of the acceleration is $\frac{30^2}{R}$ - centripetal acceleration in appropriate units - and its direction is towards the centre of the circle.

If the trajectory is not an arc of a circle then one would have to evaluate the acceleration as a function of position both in terms of magnitude but also in terms of direction.
That evaluation of $\frac {d\vec v}{dt}$ might have to be done numerical rather than analytical.

Comment: The trajectory is not an arc of a circle                                                                                           how would I, in this case, evaluate dv/dt ?

Comment: What is the trajectory?